# Migrate from Google Cloud Message to Firebase

Tags: firebase, notifications, google-cloud-messaging, push, migrate

I have a database with millions of records which contains token ID from Google Cloud Message which I used to send Push Notification to users.

Now I would like to upgrade my app. I would like to replace Google Cloud Message by Firebase.

Then can I use the old token IDs?, what do I have to do to reuse them?
Can I use them in another app?

Answer (score 0):

You can import your existing Google project into Firebase, that way your current tokens will still be valid.

From the [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com) there is a "Import Google Project" button, from that you will be able to select your existing Google project.